# Function arguments table and key value

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am trying to make a table, name given by the first arg of a function and assign a value to a key named by the second arg. For example

```
function myinsert(a, b)
    a.b = 10
```

For example when I give args pencil and price, pencil table to be created and pencil.price to be 10. Or other args, lesson and grade, making lesson.grade = 10. But as I try this it gives that it can't index local a (number value). What should I do? Thanks a lot

Comment: Add your entire code, including the part where you call the function.

Comment: Values, including tables, do no have names; variables do. Do you mean that `a` refers to a table or that `a` refers to a string that  names a variable that refers to a table?

Comment: Also note that your `b` parameter is not being used. Try an IDE that helps you understand what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the loadstring function, which will evaluate arbitrary code in string

http://www.lua.org/pil/14.1.html

Example:

```
function myinsert(a, b)
  f = loadstring(string.format("%s={}; %s.%s=10", a, a, b))
  f()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_G[a]={[b]=10}` to create a global table whose name is stored in `a`. The name of field to receive 10 is stored in `b`.

For example:

```
a = "pencil"
b = "price"
_G[a]={[b]=10}
```

is the same as

```
pencil.price=10
```

The code works even if `a` or `b` are not really *names*, that is, they don't have to be strings.